# xively status:400 with arduino and sim900 gprs shield

Tags: arduino, gprs, xively

Im using a cheap Sim900 GPRS shield with arduino and hopefully xively. I'm able to connect to xively with tcp but when i send in the data i get this response "status":400,"body":"Syntax Error: parse error: ". 
I'm using the sample from http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V1.0#SoftwareSerial_library_Notes and I've tried some modifications without any luck. I don't find documentation on how this string should look like.

My serial string looks like this:
{"method": "put","resource": "/feeds/feednumber-removed/","params": {},"headers": {"X-PachubeApiKey":"device key removed"},"body": {"version": "1.0.0","datastreams": {"id": "Sensor1","current_value": "1031"}]},"token": "123"}

Can someone please help me on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your JSON may be missing some brackets. You also have some arguments that you dont need. Try something like this instead:

```
{
    "method": "put",
    "resource": "/feeds/FEED_ID_HERE",
    "params": {},
    "headers": {"X-ApiKey":"API_KEY_HERE"},
    "body":  {
        "version" : "1.0.0",
        "datastreams": [
            {
                "id": "Sensor1",
                "current_value": "1031"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to make the bracketing as verbose and aligned as possible so you can see where the brackets need to be in order to conform to the Xively JSON format, and just correct JSON in general. I also updated the header name which has changed since the Pachube days.

Comment: Thanks calumb, now i see the feed is received by xively but the datastream isnt updated (the value isn't updated on the chart). This is the request received by xively URL /api/v2/feeds/38068201
Method PUT
At 
REQUEST HEADERS

Version HTTP/1.0
Host api.xively.com
X-Request-Start 1388932274952115
X-Apikey ixvIuwUdqviAcsIwhgUT2Wvfz9cwpzyGDIysEyJAK9Q16cl0
User-Agent Paws/0.2.03 - https://xively.com
Origin 
REQUEST BODY
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "datastream": [
    {
      "id": "Sensor1",
      "current_value": "980"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: If you see the data showing up in the request log then it is being stored. Try switching your graph to 5 Minutes and see if the data shows up.

Comment: Thanks calumb for the reply, i have tried that but I can't see any data. The last update and current value don't change. Everything looks like the data is stored, at least received but i can't figure out why it doesn't get through to the data chart. Do you have any suggestions for something to try?

Comment: Figured it out, "datastereams" missed the s when i rewrote it. Thanks calumb, couldn't have done it with out your help.